# What is The Correct Way to Use a CSS Pencil Effect On an HTML Page?

Tags: html, css, image, filter, sass

I am trying to develop an app that uses a CSS **pencil effect filter**.

The code I've copied over doesn't seem to do the same as the code on the page I got it from. In my development environment, it only converts the image into greyscale and doesn't achieve the pencil effect.

Why isn't this code working in my development environment?

**My Code:**

```
<html>
<style>
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTuYvJOVHBvDlrc_9N2QdTwltioVq1og5UkLsLo1-32kFcxhmZyYQ');
  width: 170px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  filter: grayscale(100%);

  &:after {
    content: '';
    background: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    filter: grayscale(100%) invert(100%) blur(5px);
    mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
  }
}
</style>
<body>
<div role="img"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Oringinal Code](https://jsfiddle.net/equinusocio/qtz1bykw/9/):

[image]

```
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*v-q4is6XGAQ6XLYI2m7NzQ.jpeg');
  width: 160px;
  height: 196px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  filter: grayscale(100%);

  &:after {
    content: '';
    background: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    filter: grayscale(100%) invert(100%) blur(5px);
    mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
  }
}
```

Comment: So in what way is this "not working".

Comment: you need to show us how it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You Can’t Directly Insert an SCSS (Sassy CSS) File Into Your HTML

Unfortunately, you can’t directly insert an SCSS (Sassy CSS) file into your HTML, as per your code above. That’s because SASS is a superset (or so-called preprocessor or extension) of CSS3's syntax, which is NOT supported by web browsers.

While SCSS offers many handy features for developers that do not exist in native CSS such as inheritance, nesting, logic statements, mixins, and more, it also limits you from having a link to the .scss file in your HTML page.

[image]

So to take full advantage of all the features offered by SCSS in your HTML page, you’ll first have to compile it down to CSS.

To convert your SCSS to CSS, you can use this tool:

[SCSS to CSS Converter](http://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/)

---

### Replace your current code with [This](https://jsfiddle.net/qtz1bykw/109/):

*To make this answer self-contained, I have converted it for you.

```
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*v-q4is6XGAQ6XLYI2m7NzQ.jpeg');
  width: 160px;
  height: 196px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  filter: grayscale(100%) invert(100%) blur(5px);
  mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using the code inside your own project, and not on the fiddle. If so, the external fiddle was set to be using SCSS, there's a chance that you are not compiling the SCSS to regular CSS which makes it so that the &:after part has a syntax error.

You can use a non-nested version of styling by adding div:after, rather than &:after. The following would work for you:

```
<html>
<style>
    div {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTuYvJOVHBvDlrc_9N2QdTwltioVq1og5UkLsLo1-32kFcxhmZyYQ');
        width: 170px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        filter: grayscale(100%);
    }

   div:after {
       content: '';
       background: inherit;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       filter: grayscale(100%) invert(100%) blur(5px);
       mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
   }
</style>
<body>
<div role="img"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and what's the issue? jsfiddle is working find with SCSS

Comment: it was, inspect the element to see the code and check the fiddle you will see SCSS activated ... also compare your code with his code, you will have the same output

Comment: @TemaniAfif He says that he 'got' the code from the fiddle. The code does in fact work on the fiddle, however I assume he is using it in his own project rather than on the fiddle itself.

Comment: Lesleyvdp, thank you so much, this was the first question I have proffered to stackoverflow and I have been very impressed, i have one more question if you won't be inconvenienced, is there a way to assign this code to a tag e.g. img, canvas, video e.t.c. in the form of a class.

Comment: @Zodiax No worries friend, that's what the community is for after all! I am glad I could help. If the answer helped you make sure you mark it as correct so people know the problem has been 'resolved'. Do you mean apply the grayscale effect to img, canvas or video tags?

Comment: @Lesleyvdp not just greyscale, for I can do that, but the pencil sketch itself.

Comment: @Zodiax Quickly trying it does not result in the pencil sketch effect, I will look into it for a bit longer tomorrow.

Comment: @Zodiax As Invariant Change also mentioned in the comments, please mark an answer as 'correct', just under the amount of upvotes/downvotes of the answer so people know it is completed. I am looking into your question now.